# Best way to check element present before binding function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, performance, optimization, dom

I've been using the following test/function pair in an effort to only attach functions to appropriate page elements if one or more are present:

```
function assistedSearch() {
    $('.assistedSearch').focus( function() {
        ...
    });
}
$(function() {
    if ( $('.assistedSearch').length > 0 ) {
        assistedSearch();
    }
});

function inputHinting() {
    $(':input.hint').each( function() {
        ...
    });
}
$(function() {
    if ( $(':input.hint').length > 0 ) {
        inputHinting();
    }
});
```

Is this a classic case of over-engineering?  Is the "if" test before each function binding unnecessary?

If it's not over-engineering, is there a less DOM-intensive way of ensuring only the required functions are bound to the current page?

Comment: its pointless as jQuery handles all of that by default, all you are doing is going over it again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing the method you propose you are actually losing performance since each if queries the dom and your function issues the query again.

```
function inputHinting() {
    $(':input.hint').each( function() { //query the dom again since it was found.
        ...
    });
}
$(function() {
    if ( $(':input.hint').length > 0 ) { //Query the dom for :input.hint
        inputHinting();
    }
});
```

jQuery will handle this for you as it makes sure the element is present before something is done to it.  With that being said if you *do this*, you should cache your selectors like the following:

```
function inputHinting($inputHint) {
    $inputHint.each( function() { 
        ...
    });
}
$(function() {
    var $inputHint = $(':input.hint');
    if ( $inputHint.length > 0 ) { //Query the dom for :input.hint
        inputHinting($inputHint);
    }
});
```

By doing that you only query the dom once.

Comment: Interesting approach in your "pass-through" example above. Am I right in assuming that if you end up with a zero-match variable (e.g. if $inputHint's length was 0), it would be automatically removed from memory at the end of the "ready" statement that encapsulates it? I'm thinking about memory constraints impacting performance, particularly on mobile devices.

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396264/jquery-garbage-collection-will-this-be-clean  as long as you do your operations with jQuery objects it should keep track of variables and dispose of them when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really care about that. Jquery checks internally so you don't have to worry about it. If you really must check it for some reason of your own, the `.length` property would be the way to go.

**EDIT**

Also, you don't need to do

```
if ( $(':input.hint').length > 0 ){}
```

Simply using the below is equivalent

```
if ( $(':input.hint').length) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(function(elem)
{
    if(elem.length>0)
        elem.each( function() 
        {
            ...
        });
})($(':input.hint'));
```

So this will query the dom only once, then it will pass the jquery object collection to an anonymous function and execute it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything for me; no iteration, no error - nothing. I like the idea though.